# How to set ownership of folder and permission using Filezilla

Tags: permissions, ftp, filezilla, ownership

Just want to have some answer to my question. Because I have a website and I have a file browser on my admin part. The problem is I can't upload on some of the folders. And when I checked on the console I got this error message:

```
   <b>Warning</b>: move_uploaded_file(/var/www/vhosts/mysite.com/httpdocs/image/data/Philippines/login.png): failed to open stream: Permission denied in <b>/var/www/vhosts/mysite.com/httpdocs/centre/controller/common/filemanager.php</b> on line <b>480</b><b>Warning</b>: move_uploaded_file(): Unable to move '/tmp/phpm0WqMg' to '/var/www/vhosts/mysite.com/httpdocs/image/data/Philippines/login.png' in <b>/var/www/vhosts/flaxmidoriprojects.com/httpdocs/centre/controller/common/filemanager.php</b> on line <b>480</b>{"error":"Warning: File could not be uploaded for an unknown reason!"}
```

And when I checked the permission and the group on the FTP Filezilla. These folders are in different group and permissions.

[image]

These are the folders `fle (0755)` and `48 48` group. Can you give me an idea how did this happened?

That's all thanks. I hope you can give me some idea also on how can I fix this. I already tried changing the permission on Fileilla but my operation is not permitted.

Comment: Your question is [off-topic here](//stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) - It would be on-topic on [su]. But there it's already answered: [Changing group in FileZilla](https://superuser.com/q/815793/213663)

Answer (score 2):

You'll have to change the owner using ssh or similar, using the chown command (https://linux.die.net/man/1/chown).  You can't do that through Filezilla.  Usually when you have a problem like this it is because the files were created by a program or through an interface where it assigned an owner other that you.  Your host might be able to help.  This is sometimes a configuration issues on their end that they can help with.  Make sure your .htaccess file is correct as it can help prevent problems like this.

Answer (score 2):

I can't do it in Filezilla. But I done this to solve my problem.

I had the problem in cpanel. So I have to change the file permission (Not: Only folder permission). That is web folder.

1. I renamed to webx
2. Created a new folder with the name web.
3. Moved all files from webx to web

This worked for me. I checked the permission in Filezilla, its solved.